# Some questions about the With Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am experimenting (the code as it is works) with some userform code that writes data onto a table. ST is some named Range:

```
With Range(ST)
    .Cells(Range(ST).Count).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    .Resize(Range(ST).Rows.Count + 1).Name = ST
    .Cells(Range(ST).Rows.Count, 1) = Range(ST).Rows.Count - 1
    .Cells(Range(ST).Rows.Count, 2) = TextBox2.Text
End With
```

My question is:

Why is it that I can rewrite the 2nd and third line as below without it effecting the end result

```
    .Cells(.Count).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    .Resize(.Rows.Count + 1).Name = ST
```

But the changing the other lines e.g

```
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2) = TextBox2.Text
```

Causes the Entry on the table that is supposed to contain `TextBox2.Text` to return a blank cell.

Thanks (Any other misc comments re the code also welcomed)

EDIT:

Unfortunately I posted this question precisely because of it not behaving as you guys said. After reading the help file in detail i believe the line:

"The expression is evaluated once, upon entry into the block. You can't reassign the expression from within the With block."

implies that the:

```
.Resize(Range(ST).Rows.Count + 1).Name = ST
```

was the problem and took the two lines:

```
.Cells(Range(ST).Count).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
.Resize(Range(ST).Rows.Count + 1).Name = ST
```

outside of the with block and everything worked as expected! Did I intepret this correctly?
Would anyone be interested if I uploaded the file? (toy experiment the code is less than a few lines)

Comment: Removing `Range(ST)` inside the `with end with` should not make any difference to the code

Answer (score 2):

The `With ... End` statement is very useful; it helps faster coding as well as program executing. More you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

In regards to your question; you should be able to remove `Range(ST)` in all lines inside the `With ... End` statement.

Comment: Hi unfortunately things did not work out that way. I've made an edit about what I think the problem might be. What do you think of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, you can write your code in any one of these ways. they all will do the same thing.

```
With Range(ST)
    .Cells(Range(ST).Count).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    .Resize(Range(ST).Rows.Count + 1).Name = ST
    .Cells(Range(ST).Rows.Count, 1) = Range(ST).Rows.Count - 1
    .Cells(Range(ST).Rows.Count, 2) = TextBox2.Text
End With
```

OR

```
With Range(ST)
    .Cells(.Count).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    .Resize(.Rows.Count + 1).Name = ST
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1) = .Rows.Count - 1
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2) = TextBox2.Text
End With
```

OR

```
With Range(ST)
    Dim nCount As Long

    nCount = .Rows.Count

    .Cells(.Count).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    .Resize(nCount + 1).Name = ST
    .Cells(nCount, 1) = nCount - 1
    .Cells(nCount, 2) = TextBox2.Text
End With
```

Comment: Hi unfortunnately the first 2 blocks does not give the same output in my case. I've made an edit into how I think I solved it but I'm not very sure I understood the help file correctly. Would appreciate any comments. And thanks for the reply!